# Vuforia and MRTK for Hololens 1 : ImageTarget not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, hololens, mrtk

I'm creating a simple app with a menu and multiple scenes. The structure is the following :

1. Loading (empty scene, MRTK Scene Manger, load the main scene, contains the camera)
2. Main (4 buttons used to change scene, no camera)
3. Cube (a scene with a cube, no camera)
4. Scenario1 (a scene with Vuforia and ImageTarget, contains `Vuforia Behaviour` script)
5. ...

**The problems**
I have one main issue :

When I launch the application in Unity, Vuforia use my webcam as a camera and the ImageTarget are detected really quickly. However when I deploy on the Hololens using USB method (since Vuforia isn't supported using `Hololens Remoting Player`), it's really hard to detect the ImageTarget. The ImageTarget got 4/5 stars when uploaded on Vuforia and these are my settings :
[image]
In Vuforia database I also set the height of the target to 0.21m since I printed it on a A4 sheet

There you can see the scene system I use :
[image]

For the camera, the `loading` scene contains the `Main Camera`, then in `Scenario1` I have an empty object containing `Vuforia Behaviour Script`.

**Question**

Why is Vuforia having so much troubles to detect the ImageTarget when running on the Hololens ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to [Vuforia Engine Release Notes | VuforiaLibrary](https://library.vuforia.com/release-notes/vuforia-engine-release-notes#vuforia-engine-v10-3-2), support for HoloLens 1 was deprecated in Vuforia Engine v10.3.2.

Comment: Yes but I use `Vuforia version 9.8.13`

Comment: There are some known issues related to HoloLens in Vuforia 9.8.13 to 10.3.2 release notes(https://library-archive.vuforia.com/release-notes/vuforia-engine-release-notes-0.html#vuforia-engine-v9-8-13-patch-5). Which mentions that after pause/resume the target cannot be detected and the menu gets stuck, is this similar to your issue? I suggest that you seek support from Vuforia Forum - https://developer.vuforia.com/forum.

Comment: Thank you for all your help and time, the issue was from the paper sheet I used to print the target. Seems like Vuforia prefer photography paper than normal paper [as stated in this documentation page](https://library.vuforia.com/objects/physical-properties-image-based-targets)